# Combining verbs with ecce or en

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, verbs, syntax, particle

I am puzzled about the syntactical role of *ecce* and *en*.
I feel comfortable using them with nouns (*ecce camelopardalis meus*, "here is my giraffe" or "look, my giraffe"), and I would like to know if they are compatible with verbs.
For example, if I want to say "Behold, the lion eats!", which one should I pick:

- Verb in personal form: *Ecce leo edit!*
- Participle: *Ecce leo edens!*
- Or something else?

This came up when I tried to answer [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2489/79) and translate "here comes".
I realized that I don't know how to combine verbs with *ecce* or *en*.

Comment: Since I've read the Vulgate so much, a phrase came immediately to mind for both cases: "ecce homo" and "ecce sponsus venit"

Comment: *Ecce leo edens* would draw attention to the fact that there is an eating lion nearby. *Ecce leo est* (which I think is more common than *edit*) would draw attention to the fact that a lion is eating something. It all depends on what is being emphasized, and in fact works as *behold* would in English.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That's a good summary. I considered using *est*, but decided against it to avoid confusion with the other *est*.

Comment: There's no good alternative there, since *edit* could also come from the other *edo* meaning "to bring forth"!

Comment: @C.M.Weimer True! It should be *ĕdit* or *ēst* (as opposed to *ēdit* and *ĕst*), but I don't usually like using brevia and macra (or breves and macrons?). Oh, well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *ecce* and *en* can be used with verbs/whole clauses in addition to nouns, to draw attention to some fact rather than an object. So, both *ecce* [or *en*] *leo edit* and *ecce* [*en*] *leo edens* (or *ecce* [*en*] *leonem edentem*) would work.

For *ecce* used in this way:

> ecce, Apollo...imperat ut ego illic oculos exuram (Plautus, *Men.* 840)
>
> discubitum noctu ut imus, ecce ad me advenit mulier (Plautus, *Mer.* 100)
>
> commodum cubueram et ecce Fotis mea...proximat (Apuleius, *Met.* 2.16)

For *en* used in this way:

> revocate, Quirites.... en, revocant! (Ovid, *Am.* 3.2.75)
>
> fabulam...ad auris vestras adferre decrevi, et en occipio (Apuleius, *Met.* 9.14)
>
> haec dum stupentes quaerimus, totum en mare immugit (Seneca, *Phaed.* 1025)

For *en* and *ecce* used together (!):

> en ecce...prosiluit...Iocasta (Seneca, *Oed.* 1004)

(All attestations are from *OLD*.)